# regular expression. x characters from begin and x last characters

Tags: regex

Is it possible to have 1 regular expression that gets the first 5 characters from a string.
Append a /
Get the last 2 characters from that string

Making it aliitle complexer is that the first 5 must be before the first /
And the last 2 behind the last /
If there are les characters we show less.

Help is realy apriciated

Example:
AZERT/45674 => AZERT/74
TGFERYBBCD/8 => TGFER/8

Kind regards.

Comment: I *think*  I understand what you want, but it sure would be nice to see some examples.

Comment: Sounds like homework to me...

Comment: Not realy homework.
Needed for private project.
@TimPietzcker edited the openings post and added 2 examples.

Comment: `~^([^/]{5}).*?([^/]{0,2})$~`

Comment: @zerkms Close that gets me the 2 parts needed(and on index 0 the whole element), Just need to have it on index0 and in 1 part with the / in between.

Comment: @Stijnhau how is it supposed to be obvious from the question if you **DID NOT** mention it? Please put all the requirements clearly to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As easy as

```
~^([^/]{5}).*?([^/]{0,2})$~
```

It's just a direct translation of your requirements into a regular expression

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/bB6nL4/1

Comment: You should probably change `{5}` to `{0,5}`.

Comment: I don't see that from the question. OP states it must be exactly 5 characters.

Comment: Close.
Just it is on index 1 and index2 the last part.
Index0 has the correct first part and the / but the last characters in that location are wrong

Comment: @Stijnhau: "but the last characters in that location are wrong" --- the result matches what you've demonstrated in the question.

Comment: @zerkms not when i use the php wrapper
<?php
$str = "lao/56345";
preg_match('~^([^/]{0,5}).*?([^/]{0,2})$~', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);

array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "lao/56345"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "lao"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "45"
}
 Just the last Part on index0 still needs to be fixed. :)

Comment: @Stijnhau: you cannot do that. `0` always points to the whole matched contiguous string.

Comment: @zerkms Hmm that could be an issue.
Is it possible to get the /as the 2 and the last part as the 3?

Comment: Why is it an ussue? Just take `$matches` and put it into any array in any order you want (not to say it's not clear what you meant)

Comment: @zerkms If i can get the / on index 2 and the last characters on index3 that would also help.

Comment: So put `(/)` additionally. Not to be rude, but what if you try yourself first before you ask such trivial things? Lack of knowledge is a bad justification for laziness.

Comment: ~^([^/]{0,5})(/).*?([^/]{0,2})$~
TNX
Tryed putting it in but it failed the first times.
Addes it not where i addes it now but after the . or after the * or after the ?

Comment: `(/)` must be put before the last group. Please read something about regular expressions basics

Comment: @zerkms ~^([^/]{0,5}).*?(/)([^/]{0,2})$~' Added it like that but doesn't give me some rezsults

Comment: @Stijnhau do you seriously think "doesn't give me some rezsults" is enough? If so, here is the answer: "fix it somehow then"